# Using swisstopo.dll in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I am using the dll's of swisstopo to migrate coordinates from the LV03 to the LV95 format.

I downloaded the dll's from [here](http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/de/home/products/software/products/reframe_dll.html).

The first thing I wanted to do is write a Unit Test to confirm the correctness of the migration.
I've referenced the two dll's and wrote the Unit Test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Lv03ToLv95ConverterTest
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase(600000, 200000, 2600000.0, 1200000.0)]
    public void Convert_WhenGivenLv03In_ThenExpectedLv95Out(double givenLv03Easting, double givenLv03Northing, double expectedLv95Easting, double expectedLv95Northing)
    {
        var actualLv95 = Lv03ToLv95Converter.Convert(givenLv03Easting, givenLv03Northing);
        actualLv95.Easting.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedLv95Easting);
        actualLv95.Northing.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedLv95Northing);
    }
}

public static class Lv03ToLv95Converter
{
    public static Lv95 Convert(double easting, double northing)
    {
        var reframe = new Reframe();
        var height = 0.0;
        reframe.ComputeReframe(
            ref easting,
            ref northing,
            ref height,
            Reframe.PlanimetricFrame.LV03_Civil,
            Reframe.PlanimetricFrame.LV95,
            Reframe.AltimetricFrame.LN02,
            Reframe.AltimetricFrame.LHN95);

        return new Lv95(easting, northing);
    }
}

public class Lv95
{
    public Lv95(double easting, double northing)
    {
        this.Easting = easting;
        this.Northing = northing;
    }

    public double Easting { get; private set; }

    public double Northing { get; private set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I want to run the test, it says:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load the specified file.
>
> at swisstopo.geodesy.htrans.CHtrans.ReadData(Single[,]& data, String filename)
>
> at swisstopo.geodesy.htrans.CHtrans.ComputeHtrans(Double& height, Double east, Double north, HeightTransformation transformation)
>
> at swisstopo.geodesy.reframe.Reframe.TransformAltimetry(Double& height, Double east, Double north, AltimetricFrame altFrameIn, AltimetricFrame altFrameOut)
>
> at swisstopo.geodesy.reframe.Reframe.ComputeReframe(Double& east, Double& north, Double& height, PlanimetricFrame plaFrameIn, PlanimetricFrame plaFrameOut, AltimetricFrame altFrameIn, AltimetricFrame altFrameOut)
>
> at MyProject.Tests.Lv03ToLv95Converter.Convert(Double easting, Double northing) in C:\Projects\MyProject\sources\MyProject.Tests\Lv03ToLv95ConverterTest.cs:line 33
>
> at MyProject.Tests.Lv03ToLv95ConverterTest.Convert_WhenGivenLv03In_ThenExpectedLv95Out(Double givenLv03Easting, Double givenLv03Northing, Double expectedLv95Easting, Double expectedLv95Northing) in C:\Projects\MyProject\sources\MyProject.Tests\Lv03ToLv95ConverterTest.cs:line 21

Does anyone know what's the problem here?
I've never had issues referencing and using a dll before...

thanks in advance

***Edit:*** we think the problem could be, that Reframe is calling Assembly.ExecutingAssembly and looking for swisstopo.data etc. in the path which it doesn't find, because the executing assembly is the nunit runner...

We've tried to load the assemblies manually inside the test but unfortunately didn't work as well.

```
[Test]
    [TestCase(600000, 200000, 2600000.0, 1200000.0)]
    public void Convert_WhenGivenLv03In_ThenExpectedLv95Out(double givenLv03Easting, double givenLv03Northing, double expectedLv95Easting, double expectedLv95Northing)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("swisstopo.data");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("swisstopo.reframelib");
        var actualLv95 = Lv03ToLv95Converter.Convert(givenLv03Easting, givenLv03Northing);
        actualLv95.Easting.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedLv95Easting);
        actualLv95.Northing.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedLv95Northing);
    }
```

Comment: Do you reference these probably required assemblies in your test project? Did you set Copy Local to True for those assemblies, so that they are copied into the bin folder?

Comment: Yes I've referenced the assemblies in the test project and set Copy Local to true

Comment: The spec for FileLoadException (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is saying that it is thrown when a managed assembly is found but could not be loaded. It should also tell you which file it tried to load. Can you please post for the full exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with loading the "swisstopo.data" assembly in NUnit.
For me, using MS Test instead of NUnit solved the problem. In MS Test, the executing assembly is the test assembly.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Convert_WhenGivenLv03In_ThenExpectedLv95Out()
    {
        double givenLv03Easting = 600100, givenLv03Northing = 200100, expectedLv95Easting = 2600100.08309925, expectedLv95Northing = 1200100.06755549;
        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        Console.WriteLine(executingAssembly);

        var actualLv95 = Lv03ToLv95Converter.Convert(givenLv03Easting, givenLv03Northing);

        actualLv95.Easting.Should().BeApproximately(expectedLv95Easting, 0.00001);
        actualLv95.Northing.Should().BeApproximately(expectedLv95Northing, 0.00001);
    }
```